# Can an AIR application detect that computer went to sleep mode?

Tags: air, sleep

I want to deal with shutdown and sleep. For shutdown, I can listen for the application exiting event. But how should I detect entering and leaving from sleep mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't post answers smaller than 30 characters. So, I just wanted to say:

**NO**